# HTML Unordered List CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a unordered list, with each list element containing two spans (say span A and span B).
Now I need to format these so that they are placed horizontally across the screen, when span A always on top of span B.

```
Eg.  spanAItem1 spanAItem2 spanAItem3
     spanBItem1 spanBItem2 spanBItem3
```

How can I do this using some creative CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this will get you close:

```
ul {float: left; list-style-type:none;}
ul li {float: left; margin-right:20px;}
ul li span {display:block}
```

*edited to address your comment. Take it from there :)

Comment: float:left elements without a clear:both before closing the parent element (</ul> in this case) will yield funny results so you must be careful with that.

Comment: Thats pretty close to what I need.  i just need to remove the bullets themselves, and add more space between elements. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Following Triptych's response:

- Be sure to add a `<br clear="all" />` or a `<div style="clear: both"></div>` or anything that implements `clear:both` behaviour after the `</ul>` tag.
- To remove the bullets, use the `list-style-type` property:

`ul {float: left; list-style-type: none;}`

- To add more space between elements, use the `margin` property:

`ul li {float: left; margin: 10px;}`

Answer (score 1):

To add on to @Joel Alejandro and @Tryptych, if you set a width to the `ul`, the `li`s will wrap to the next line. However, IE6 will not wrap properly, so if older browsers are a concern, adding a class of "row" to the element at the beginning of every row along with `.row{clear:both}` will be the best solution, as @Joel Alejandro noted.